# Delphi iPad project splash graphic to fill the screen

Tags: delphi, retina-display

Using Delphi 11.3 with patch 1.

Creating a new blank project for the iPad results in deploying this file:
FM_LaunchScreenImage_iPad@2x.png of type iPad_Launch2x.
The source .png is 458x792.

The result is a splash screen on my iPad Pro that is far smaller than the iPad's screen size. I expected the iPad to scale the graphic to fill the screen.

How do I get a splash graphic that fills the iPad's screen?